# Command to Bulk Compress All Files / Folders Under a Directory

Tags: command-line, command, archive, bulk, compression

I'm looking for a command that will compress every folder within a directory separately with the name of each archive reflecting the original folder name. I know that

tar czvf example.tar.gz example/

will compress an entire folder. However, I have not found a command to bulk archive. Is there such a command?

Comment: Yeah, I see find, xargs and sed in your future.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec tar czf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Note that I used `-maxdepth 1`.

Consider the directory structure:

```
.
|-- a
|   `-- x
|-- b
`-- c
```

Without `-maxdepth 1` you would get `a.tar.gz` and `a/x.tar.gz`.  `a.tar.gz` would contain x and all of the files within; and `a/x.tar.gz` would contain x and its files.  But this stores the items within x twice, assuming that isn't the goal.

**Updated** to use `-mindepth 1` as well, because when run outside of `example/` an `example.tar.gz` would be created as well.

**Update** ... and for bzip2:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec tar cjf {}.tar.bz2 {} \;
```

Comment: Without -mindepth 1, won't it create an archive for the current directory?

Comment: I thought that too, but when I tested it I didn't see that happening.

Comment: Ah but if you execute it within "example/" it doesn't, if you don't, it does.  Will update.

Comment: is it possible to adjust the command so that bzip2 is used for compression?

Comment: @opello: Since the find command is finding '.', wouldn't it create a file called '..tar.gz'?  ls wouldn't show that by default.

Comment: @undoIT: change 'tar czf' to 'tar cjf' and change the extension from '.gz' to '.bz2'.  @Adam Crume: It doesn't seem to be the case, at least for me and findutils 4.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do
    tar -czf $f.tar.gz $f
done
```

Comment: Okay, one more question. If I want to compress to bzip2, what would the full command be?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the final command I came up with to archive then compress with bzip2 for maximum compression

find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec tar cjf '{}'.tar.bz2 '{}' \;

thanks everyone!